# Замена текста с промежуточным редактированием

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Начнем сразу с примера:

```
$str = "[[Яша|ya.ru]] qwerty [[Яков|yandex.ru]]";
$str = preg_replace('/\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]/','<a href="$2" target="_blank">$1</a>',$str);
echo $str;
```

Строку **$str** я принимаю от пользователя.
В принципе, код выше работает, но не производится ни какой проверки.
Как то можно повлиять на найденные **$1** и **$2** в ***preg_replace*** перед тем как они будут использованы?

Возможно я не так пошел, и есть более правильное решение, буду рад выслушать.

Comment: дак не заменяйте, найдите соответствия, обработайте, потом составьте нужную результирующую строку. именно такое поведение вы и хотите реализовать, или нет?

Comment: или `preg_replace_callback()`

Comment: @borodatych  "_(Как то можно повлиять на найденные $1 и $2)_" - в preg_replace() нет, но можно в preg_replace_callback(), как уже было сказано выше. Вообще "влиять" надо на шаблон регулярного выражения, как вы его составите, такой результат и будет найден.

Comment: @teran, благодарю за наводку, вполне подходит. Если оформите примером, хоть плюсану, если есть желание.

Comment: @borodatych аналогичный [пример с preg_replace_callback()](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38154b9c3a5e1ebc1d7eab31cf0544e00602228b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обработки захваченных значений во время замены можно воспользоваться функцией [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Она применяется тогда, когда необходимо произвести какие-нибудь действия с захваченными подстроками перед тем, как вставить их в изменённую стоку.

[Пример кода](https://3v4l.org/BkYsj), который заменяет слова на основе ассоциированного массива и переводящий имена доменов в верхний регистр:

```
$str = '[[Яша|ya.ru]] qwerty [[Яков|yandex.ru]]';
$dict = ['Яша' => 'Яков', 'Яков' => 'Яша'];      // Словарь для замены имён
$res = [];                                       // Массив для найденных имён

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)]]~',
    function ($m) use ($dict, &$res) {     // $m - объект совпадения, $m[0] - всё совпадение, $m[1] - значение первой группы и т.д.
        array_push($res, $m[1]);           // Добавление в массив найденных имён
        return '<a href="'.
          mb_strtoupper($m[2]) .           // Значение группы №2 в верхний регистр
          '" target="_blank">'. 
          (isset($dict[$m[1]]) ? $dict[$m[1]] : $m[1]) . // Замена имени из словаря, если имеется
          '</a>';
    },
    $str
) . "\n";
print_r($res); // Вывод найденных имён
```

Результат:

```
<a href="YA.RU" target="_blank">Яков</a> qwerty <a href="YANDEX.RU" target="_blank">Яша</a>
Array
(
    [0] => Яша
    [1] => Яков
)
```

Обратите внимание на `use ($dict, &$res)`: `$dict` можно использовать только для чтения, а `&$res` - для чтения и записи (благодаря `&`).

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант, не без помощи @teran:

```
$str = "[[Яша|ya.ru]] qwerty [[Яков|yandex.ru]]";
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)]]~',function ($m){
    $link = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($m[2]));
    $text = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($m[1]));
    if( strpos($link,'http')===FALSE ) $link = "http://$link";
    return '<a href="'. $link .'" target="_blank" class="solid">'. $text .'</a>';
},$str);
echo $str;
```