# Как описать переменную в preg_replace_callback?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Изначально использовал preg_replace, но с апдейтом php пришлось перейти на preg_replace_callback.
Соответственно возникла проблема, в preg_replace можно было без проблем добавить переменную, так как она не используется в виде функции при замене, но как описать переменную в preg_replace_callback?
Пример:

```
$param='TEXT';
$cont='hello world</body123>';
$cont=preg_replace_callback('/<\/body(.*?)>/i',function($matches) { return "$param\n</body$matches[1]>\n"; },$cont, 1);
echo $cont;
```

Возникет ошибка `Notice: Undefined variable: param`

Как правильно добавить переменную $param в замену?

Comment: `function(...) use ($param){ ... }`

Comment: @teran Супер! Сработало! Спасибо!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Замена текста с промежуточным редактированием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/792421/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изучайте язык, читайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php):

> **Анонимные функции**
>   Анонимные функции, также известные как замыкания (closures), позволяют создавать функции, не имеющие определенных имен. Они наиболее полезны в качестве значений callback-параметров, но также могут иметь и множество других применений.
>
> Замыкания могут также наследовать переменные из родительской области видимости. Любая подобная переменная должна быть объявлена в конструкции use. Начиная с PHP 7.1, эти переменные не должны включать superglobals, $this и переменные с теми же именами, что и параметры функции.
>
> *Пример #3 Наследование переменных из родительской области видимости*

```
$message = 'привет';
$example = function () use ($message) {
    var_dump($message);
};
```